# Match two rows in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to `google script` and I want to compare two rows from two sheets & if any cell data value matches it'll increase a value. But I'm getting an error like this,

> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

Here are my codes,

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var ans_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Correct_Answers');
var getValues = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var realValues = ans_sheet.getRange(2, 1, ans_sheet.getLastRow(), ans_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
for (var i in getValues) {
    for (var j in getValues[i]) {
        var matched = 0;
        if (getValues[i][j] == realValues[i][j]) {
            matched++;
        } else {
            getValues.push(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong here but since I'm new I can't figure it out. Need this help badly from experts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because the two ranges have different lengths or because you are appending 1's to the first array in which case there is also nothing to subscript.

At some point you are trying to access the first column (index 0) of a row that is not in the other range or the first column of 1 which does not exist.

since you are iterating through getValues you can do a check at the beginning of the loop.

```
for (var i in getValues) {
    if(i == realValues.length){break;}
    for (var j in getValues[i]) {
        if(j == realValues[j].length){break;}
        var matched = 0;
        if (getValues[i][j] == realValues[i][j]) {
            matched++;
        }
    }
}
```